# Gerundive - Gerund - Gérondif

Tags: grammaticality

*Do we use the Gerund in German language? Or the Infinitive? Is the word used?

My last question, is there someone who can explain it to me? Tschüss!*

Comment: The existing answers talked about the gerund.  But you also asked about the infinitive.  I think that German does have an infinitive (the form of the verb you see in the dictionary, and also the main verb in your sentence, e.g. I can see, Ich kann **sehen**) but I don't know what to call it in German.  I'm not sure I understood what you want explained.

Answer (score 3):

The word *Gerundium* is used (e.g. to describe another languages), but German has none.

Answer (score 3):

German doesn't have a separate verb form that would work like the gerund in English or the gérondif in French to build a substantive.

You can, however, use a substantiated verb using the infinitive that sort of works like the English or French counterpart.

> He sings while working
>
> Il chante en travaillant
>
> Er singt beim Arbeiten

Comment: Is "beim Arbeiten" considered formal? Since the sentence in English uses "while" I would rather try to translate it using während, although I don't know how to do so. Would something like "Er singt während er arbeitet" or "Er singt während Arbeitens" be correct? Thank you!